# EX of area of a circle

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

In a circle $k(O,r)$ we have fixed point A, point B lands randomly on the circle. Find $EX$ of the area of the triangle $AOB$

What I have tried : since the area of the triangle will be $ \frac{1}{2}*r^2(sin(\alpha))$ where $\alpha$ is from 0 to 360 degrees then we have to find the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2}*\alpha*r^2(sin(\alpha))\, d\alpha$  .Not sure if I am correct or missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area of a triangle is $\displaystyle ab\sin{C}$.

Consider the scenario where $O$ is the origin, and $A$ is fixed to the positive $x$ axis, from $0$ to $r_1$.

Then, in polar coordinates, let $B$ be $(r_2,\theta)$, where $\theta$ ranges from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.

The area of this triangle is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}r_1r_2|\theta|$.

So that means the average value of the integral is $\displaystyle \frac{2}{2\pi r^2}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^r\int_0^r\frac{1}{2}r_1 r_2\sin(\theta)\,dr_1\,dr_2\,d\theta$.

Notice that I made the integral symmetric by noting the area is the same for $\theta$ and $-\theta$, hence the last bound only ranging from $0$ to $\pi$, and a corresponding $2$ in the numerator.

---

In your case, which I just realized, $a$ is fixed. Eliminate $r_1$ from the integral, and now you just have $\displaystyle \frac{2}{2\pi r}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^r\frac{1}{2}r_1 r_2\sin(\theta)\,dr_2\,d\theta$.

Comment: where did $\frac{2}{2\pi *r}$ come from and also $r_{1}=r_{2}$ always so we can replace them with $r$ ?

Comment: @Steffen $r_1$ is not necessarily equal to $r_2$, though they are both less than or equal to $r$. the $2$ is because the integral only goes from $0$ to $\pi$, not from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. the $2\pi r$ is for the purpose of expected value, so i'm dividing by $2\pi r$, which is the total range of possibilities for both $\theta$ and $r_2$.

Comment: is there a general formula that describes this metod of solving?

Comment: it's called geometric probability